# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string

I am trying to generate a random number convert it to and int then print the number, but i am getting the error 'str' object is not callable. I have googled the problem but I cant seem to find what i am doing wrong.

here is my code:

```
import random
import time

while(True):
    #generate a random frequency from 0Hz to 1MHz   
    frequency = int(random.randrange(0,1000000))    
    print('Frequency: %d'('frequency'))
    print('Frequency: ',frequency, ' Hz')

    print("sleep for 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)  # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds)
```

The error i get is:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "frequency1.py", line 7, in <module>
print('Frequency: %d'('Frequency'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: `('Frequency: %d') %(frequency)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your print statement is incorrect. It should instead be

```
print('Frequency: %d'%(frequency))
```

When you do `'Frequency: %d'(frequency)`, You are trying to call the string `'Frequency: %d'` as a function. This is why you get the error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`. The error can be decoded as `'str' object` which is `'Frequency: %d'` is not *callable* i.e. it is not a function that can be called

You can try `format` instead as it is better. Do read [PEP - 3101](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) that mentions about `format` and the `%` operator. The print statement can be written as

```
print('Frequency: {}'.format(frequency))
```

---

The changed program after correcting the missing `%` symbol can be written as

```
import random
import time

while(True):
    #generate a random frequency from 0Hz to 1MHz   
    frequency = int(random.randrange(0,1000000))    
    print('Frequency: %d'%(frequency))            # Note the added % 
    print('Frequency: ',frequency, ' Hz')

    print("sleep for 2 seconds")
    time.sleep(2)  # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds)
```

This program on execution would give the following output.

```
Frequency: 753865
Frequency:  753865  Hz
sleep for 2 seconds
Frequency: 152017
Frequency:  152017  Hz
sleep for 2 seconds
```

---

Also note that the `,` in python adds a space. Hence you need not do `print('Frequency: ',frequency, ' Hz')` but instead can directly write `print('Frequency:',frequency, 'Hz')`.

Comment: Thank you all i was missing was that % before (frequency). the joys of learning a new language from scratch and having to learn how it passes values ha

Comment: The solution is correct, but the reason for the error is wrong. It's not related to the type that `%d` expects, because the code wasn't using the `%` formatting operator. Without the operator, `'Frequency: %d'(...)` tries to call the string `'Frequency %d'` as a function.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks again for your comment. Please do go through the answer and the [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27860778/revisions). Kindly indicate any other changes that are required. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation is done using the `%` operator, but you're trying to call the string as if it were a function instead which explains the error.

It should be:

```
print("Frequency: %d" % frequency)
```

Note that the right-hand side of the `%` only needs to be a tuple if there is more than one value, single values can be passed bare like above.

Also, in Python 3 it's more common with the more modern `format()` syntax:

```
printf("Frequency: {}".format(frequency))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> while(True):
...     frequency = int(random.randrange(0,1000000))    
...     print('Frequency: %d'%frequency)
...     print('Frequency: ',frequency, ' Hz')
...     time.sleep(2)  # Delay for 1 minute (60 seconds)
```

...

OUtput

Frequency: 720460
('Frequency: ', 720460, ' Hz')

Frequency: 559979
('Frequency: ', 559979, ' Hz')

Frequency: 649103
('Frequency: ', 649103, ' Hz')